# Comparing string against list of strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, hash, string-comparison

If I have a list of strings for example:

```
Dog
Cat
Tree
NiceCar
Car
```

And then I get one string from list what is the fastest way to check them? I was thinking about some hashing and then to comparing the hashes.

```cpp
std::hash<std::string> hasher;

std::string stringToCheck = "Car";

switch (hasher(stringToCheck))
{
    case hasher("Dog"):
       break;
    // and so on, I will ofcourse hash the whole list on program start and then compare against that.
}
```

Comment: You've probably already noticed that `case hasher("Dog"):` doesn't compile

Comment: You may have noticed that `case hasher("Dog"):`, even if it did compile, would result in false positive matches.

Comment: "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain." -- Scotty, Star Trek III. The `==` operator is fast enough already.

Comment: How long is the list going to be? For the five items in the question, just putting them in an array and doing a linear search with `operator==` is plenty fast. Even up to a few hundred items that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I will ofcourse hash the whole list on program start and then compare against that.

If that's the case, I would suggest using a standard library utility - `std::unordered_set`, which internally stores the data and uses hashing to search for it:

```
int main() {
    std::unordered_set<std::string> strings = {
            "dog", "cat", "tree", "nicecar", "car"
    };

    std::string to_search = "dog";

    std::cout << strings.contains(to_search); // true
    std::cout << strings.contains("not there"); // false
}
```

But do note that this incurs additional costs - the creation of the set (and, in reality, any mean of hashing the data beforehand) will take additional time. This is only worth it if you query the elements from the set multiple times. Otherwise, plain old `==` will be sufficient. To compare the approaches you can't do anything else than measure the time taken of each of them.

EDIT: It appears that you wish to retain the `switch-case` functionality. For completeness, to achieve similar effect I would recommend not a *set*, but a *map*. Specifically, `std::unordered_map`:

```
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, void (*)()> cases = {
            {"dog", [](){
                std::cout << "this is a dog";
            }},
            {"cat", [](){
                std::cout << "meow";
            }},
            {"tree", [](){
                std::cout << "to isengard";
            }},
            {"nicecar", [](){
                std::cout << "goes brrrr";
            }},
            {"car", [](){
                std::cout << "wroom";
            }}
    };

    const std::string to_search = "dog";

    cases[to_search]();
}
```

This prints `this is a dog`.

The only upside of this approach vs the `switch()` approach is that with this container, you can dynamically add, remove and modify the keys and the executed code.

Comment: this only tells me if the string is in the list -> doesnt work in if else or switch

Comment: Id does. `if(strings.contains("not there")) { ... } else { ... }`. If these are not sufficient, you have to edit your question to show what would you like to do with such results.

Comment: Or `strings.count("not there")` if not using C++20.

Comment: @jisojeb400 please see the edit, since I think I now understand what you had in mind. If not, feel free to correct me.